# What's a good way to Join large amounts of data between two microservice?

Tags: join, architecture, microservices

We are making the system for libraries with a Microservice Architecture. There are two microservices, one is the Book microservice, another is the Author microservice. Each microservice provides a REST API and has its own database table. Because they have a N:N relationship, we create a join table in the Book microservice's database.

In this situation, we were asked to implement a function that downloads the information of all books in one library as an Excel file along with the author's name. The number of books covered is 1 million, and the number of applicable authors reaches 600,000.

Should we pass all 600,000 foreign keys as payloads to a REST API? And should we query by putting all the foreign keys in the IN statement?

If the data were in one database, it is a problem that can be easily solved with JOIN. What is the best way to join large amounts of data between microservices?

Comment: How often do you need to generate this report? Are there any similar report requests as well? Is the report available to external customers as well, or is it internal only?

Comment: There is no best way to join large amounts of data between microservices.  Every choice (whether you have microservices or not), will entail tradeoffs.

Comment: @PeterCsala Our client wants this feature to be available all the time, but it is assumed that it will be used typically once a month. There are no similar requests yet, but there is a possibility that there will be in the future. This feature is for internal use only and is never planned for external customers.

Comment: @LeviRamsey We thought the same as you, but we posted this question in case anyone has a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Let me put here my 2 cents

#### SOA vs Microservices

Whenever we are talking about microservices then we are thinking about a fine grained domain segregation. On the other hand in case of SOA we are more concerned about cohesion via bounded contexts that's why there the services are more coarse grained.

If you would need to expose via customer APIs the author lookups (or the other direction: book lookups) then it would make more sense to prefer data locality over independent deployments.

#### Cache vs ETL

Based on your comment it seems like your use cases is more like a reporting scenario with either scheduled or ad-hoc executions. You have also mentioned that it is for internal use mainly.

If you would have to perform author/book lookups based on customer requests then the requested quantity would be fairly low (compared to the total catalog). By caching the looked up values into a distributed cache (like Redis) could be a good idea to minimize the communication between the microservices. Books, authors and their relationship can be considered as fairly static data so, they are good candidates for caching.

Since we are talking about internal reports I would personally suggest a different path. Copy both microservices' data into a common data storage via ETL jobs. Either via having a continuous change-data-capture (CDC) solution or via predefined (for example daily scheduled) extract-transform-load jobs.

This approach does not violate the microservice principles. Basically we just introduced a read replica for the operation data for resource and time intensive analysis. If there will be new reporting requests then they could be easily added to this.